Neumorphism Transition Animation
I'm trying to animate my button when its hovered, but the transition animation is not working.
Idle State
Hovered State
Here is the CSS:
body {
    background-color: #292D32;
}

#btn {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    border:none;
    background-color: #292D32;
    color: #BEC6BE;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    box-shadow: 
    10px 10px 15px #1C1E20, 
    -10px -10px 15px #3A3E42;
    transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease;
}

#btn:hover {
    box-shadow: 
    inset 10px 10px 15px #1C1E20, 
    inset -10px -10px 15px #3A3E42;
}

I tried using transition as described above but it didn't work; I was expecting a smooth animation where the button as shown in the second picture

Welcome to Stack Overflow. We need to see the HTML for your code as well; please edit your question to include the HTML like you've already done for the CSS. See [mcve] for more information on what I mean, if you have questions.

" If in any pair of shadows, one has inset set and the other does not, the entire shadow list is uninterpolated; the shadows will change to the new values without an animating effect." from:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow#interpolation
